# Raising a Complex Number to a Power

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $ z = \cos\frac{\pi}{24} + \sin\frac{\pi}{24}$.

Compute $ a,b $ such that $ z^8 = a + bi $.

Applying De Moivre's Theorem I get this:

$ z^8 = (\cos\frac{\pi}{24} + i \sin\frac{\pi}{24})^8 $

$ z = \frac12 +\frac {\sqrt{3}} 2i $

I am not sure of the answer, I think it can be done in other ways as well, but I can't think of anything.

How would you do tackle it?

Comment: Did you mean $i\sin(\pi/24)$ instead of $\sin(\pi/24)$?

Comment: Also, you last line should still contain "$z^8$", not just "$z$".

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$ e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta+i\sin\theta $$

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?